# Цвет фона datePicker view iOS

Tags: ios, swift, color

Как установить цвет фона в datePicker view в iOS? При установке цвета например как datePicker.backgroundColor = UIColor.black цвет изменяется, но при попытке получить цвет background возвращается nil. Что не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

можно так получить `myDatePicker.subviews[0].backgroundColor`